# What does "all rot" mean in here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I expect someone lives there in
>   secret, only coming in and out at
>   night, with a dark lantern. We shall
>   probably discover a gang of desperate
>   criminals and get a reward. **It's all
>   rot to say** a house would be empty
>   all those years unless there was some
>   mystery.

**rot**
verb /rɒt//rɑːt/ [I or T] (-tt-)
Definition:
to (cause to) decay
  *The fruit had been left to rot on the trees.*
  *Rain has got in and rotted (away) the woodwork.*
  *the smell of rotting fruit*

Doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Rot* in this context is a noun which means "nonsense." In that sentence, "all rot" could probably be replaced by *ridiculous* or *absurd* and still mean generally the same thing.

Comment: I think of "It's all rot" as a particularly British expression.

Comment: Think of the implications of rot: "falls apart easily," "smells bad," "not useful'

Comment: we used to say "all rot" = "rubbish" for the same reasons as horatio has put

Comment: @KitFox. British. Upper-middle-class. Seen most often in children's detective fiction of a certain vintage. The phrase *it's all rot* immediately makes me think of Enid Blyton.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox -- Certainly "rot", in this sense, is well-known in the US.

Answer (score 5):

It is a common enough idiom in Britain so that C. S. Lewis, whom you quote, wouldn't have thought twice about using it.  One must think of idioms metaphorically, because literally, as you correctly observe, they don't "make sense."  If something has *some* rot, it is partially usable, if it is "all rot,"  then no part of it is salvageable and it should all be thrown away.  In this case, "all rot" means there is not a shred of truth in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Don't take it so literally. "Rot" in this context means "rubbish" or "B.S.", "garbage", or simply "nonsense".
Other terms with the same meaning are: baloney, bosh, balderdash, bunk, eyewash, hogwash, hooey, poppycock, tommyrot, trash, twaddle, tripe, etc.